# Button click doesn't lead to Listview to update it's value

Tags: c#, listview, mvvm, binding

Very simple situation but I am quite stuck here. In the past I have worked in the teams which written MVVM architecture codes, however this is literately the first little program that I am trying to write using MVVM arch. from the ground up.

I have a button which fires up a method called `Find()`. And this part just works fine. 
I also have set up a binding for a Listview to read the data which `Find()` method is going to change.

Code snippets are as followed:

```
    public ICommand FindBlueToothCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_findBlueToothCommand == null)
            {
                _findBlueToothCommand = new RelayCommand(param => Find());
            }
            return _findBlueToothCommand;
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<BluetoothDeviceInfo> DiscoveredDevicesList
    {
        get
        {
            return this._discoverdDevicesList;
        }
        set
        {
            this._discoverdDevicesList = value;
            base.OnPropertyChanged("DiscoveredDevicesList");
        }

    }

    private ObservableCollection<BluetoothDeviceInfo> _discoverdDevicesList;

    #endregion //Presentation Properties
```

My `Find()` method

```
   public void Find()
    {


        bool inRange;
        Guid fakeUuid = new Guid("{F13F471D-47CB-41d6-9609-BAD0690BF891}"); 
        // A specially created value, so no matches.
        var cli = new BluetoothClient();

        //BluetoothDeviceInfo[] device = cli.DiscoverDevices();
        //_discoverdDevicesList = new ObservableCollection<BluetoothDeviceInfo[]>();
        _discoverdDevicesList = new ObservableCollection<BluetoothDeviceInfo>(cli.DiscoverDevices());
       .
       .
       .
     }
```

And my XAML code

```
<Window x:Class="BlueTooth_Tester_MVVM.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Blue Tooth Tester v1.0" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource
        x:Key="DeviceList"
        Source="{Binding Path=DiscoveredDevicesList}">

    </CollectionViewSource>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="250"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListView 
        Grid.Row="0" 
        DataContext="{StaticResource DeviceList}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding}">            
    </ListView>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Button" Command="{Binding Path=FindBlueToothCommand}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Margin="5"/>

</Grid>
```

In this process if I put the `Find()` in my ViewModel's constructor I can see the list of the devices. However when I go the way that I want the program to work, when the button is pressed, using break point I can see my `_discoverdDevicesList' is getting updated and filled with values but this doesn't make it's way to the listview as it should. seems binding doesn't sense the change happened to this variable.

would be nice if you give me a hand on this.

Cheers

Comment: Instead of reassigning your collection to a new instance, have you tried calling Clear() followed by Add()?

Comment: Well I get the results as a list in one whole from the output of `cli.DiscoverDevices()` then I prefer to assign the whole thing to my _discoverdDevicesList. 
Probably a LINQ sentence can assign all it's members to my variable in one simple sentence instead of looping through. 
But my question is how come my binding doesn't sense the change which happened to _discoverdDevicesList?

Comment: I'm wondering if the listview is only watching the original ObservableCollection instance and doesn't notice if the property gets completely reassigned.

Comment: And how could I make sure of that? Do you need an other snippet of the code for extra info? or something that I can check myself?

Comment: Ye, that worked. Fantastic. So is there any way to add the whole in one command instead of foreach and add one by one? I also appreciate it if you put it as an answer then i'll mark it as the right one.

Comment: I guess you can call `OnPropertyChanged("DiscoveredDevicesList");` after calling `ObservableCollection` constructor in your `Find()` method. This is necessary beacuse you update the private variable and nobody notifies WPF Binding engine that the public property has been changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of

```
_discoverdDevicesList = new ObservableCollection<BluetoothDeviceInfo>(cli.DiscoverDevices());
```

you should do

```
  DiscoveredDevicesList= new ObservableCollection<BluetoothDeviceInfo>(cli.DiscoverDevices());
```

otherwise OnPropertyChanged() is not fired.

and even better just initialize your collection once and use clear, add , remove to alter it.

```
 DiscoveredDevicesList.Clear()
 foreach(var item in cli.DiscoverDevices())
    DiscoveredDevicesList.Add(item);
```

Comment: Fantastic. I found out this just last night when I was working with a button instead of list view. For some reason I was thinking the dummy variable should be updated in Binding method. Thanks heaps for the response.

Comment: I got some additional question on this. I took your advice and used `Add` and `Clear` after I initialized my collection and it worked. However, now I am updating a field from one of the entries in the `ListView` and I got all the bindings in place and using the right variable `DisveredDevicesList` but my list view doesn't follow the change and doesn't update himself. Is there anything I am missing here. The code is exactly as above and the only change I am considering is to use the right variable as you suggested. Are there more changes that I need to put in action to make it happen?

Comment: This is what I've put in the button click for the test purpose `DiscoveredDevicesList[0].GpsSignal = false;` and the change doesn't show up when I click the button but when I attempt to add another entry using `Add()`

Comment: if you edit an item in your collection your object should implement INotifyPropertyChanged. then you see the changes in your view (with the right binding of course :) in your case BluetoothDeviceInfo need to implement and raise INotifyPropertyChanged. just create a new question if its not working

Comment: As you asked I updated it in the body of a new question. This is the question I put it into "Listview binding doesn't update the view"

Comment: and the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23053205/listview-binding-doesnt-update-the-view