# Listview binding doesn't update the view

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm

I have this setup for my `ListView` and I am trying to make *Binding* to work in my MVVM structure.

This is the `xaml` code:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource
        x:Key="DeviceList"
        Source="{Binding Path=DiscoveredDevicesList}">

    </CollectionViewSource>
</Window.Resources>
    <ListView
    Grid.Row="1" 
    Width="500"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    Margin="10"
    Grid.Column="1"
    DataContext="{StaticResource DeviceList}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Device name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=DeviceName}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Rssi" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Rssi}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="GPS Row" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=GpsSignal}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

And the following is the code to implement the binding

```
    //Constructor 
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        DiscoveredDevicesList = new ObservableCollection<MyDeviceInfo>();
    }

    private ObservableCollection<MyDeviceInfo> _DiscoveredDevicesList;
    public ObservableCollection<MyDeviceInfo> DiscoveredDevicesList
    {
        get
        {
            return _DiscoveredDevicesList;
        }
        set
        {
            _DiscoveredDevicesList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("DiscoveredDevicesList");
        }
    }
```

Using `Add()` and `Clear()` updates the view just fine when used as below:

```
        var client = new BluetoothClient();
        DiscoveredDevicesList.Clear();
        IEnumerable<MyDeviceInfo> csaDevices = null;
        csaDevices = await DiscoverCsaDevicesAsync(client);

        foreach (var csaDevice in csaDevices)
        {
            DiscoveredDevicesList.Add(csaDevice);
            DiscoveredDevicesList.First().GpsSignal = true;
        }
```

So I can see the value of `GpsSignal` as changed to `ture` from initial opposite in my view.

However, if I put the following same line in the `OnClick` of a button doesn't do the same and the value stays `false` since I am not using any `Add()` or `Clear()` and I simply rely on the `OnPropertyChanged` to do the trick for me.

```
            DiscoveredDevicesList.First().GpsSignal = true;
```

The rest of the bindings such as button clicks and textblock information work fine, then I would assume it shouldn't be the problem with implementation of the binding on the back of the stage.

Would appreciate your suggestions on this.

Comment: Try changing the binding mode to TwoWay.

Comment: Is it a small change. Or totally a whole new topic? I am sorry if this sounds very basic

Comment: <GridViewColumn Header="GPS Row" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=GpsSignal, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

Comment: Does `MyDeviceInfo` implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` as well?

Comment: post the code from your MyDeviceInfo. there you need the right implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: `MyDeviceInfo` is basically a simple Class which I derived from `BluetoothDeviceInfo` which is a library for handling bluetooth created by 32feet. I doubt that this library has any `INotifyPropertyChange` implementation in it at all. However I have a `baseViewModel` class which I have all the Binding background stuff in it.

Comment: if the class your are binding to is not implementing INotifyPropertyChanged you will never see changes in your xaml when working with bindings. you can create a wrapper and bind to the wrapper properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your MyDeviceInfo class implement INotifyPropertyChanged and your property GpsSignal raise OnPropertyChanged() you should see all changes when your bindings are right.

nevertheless i would change your code in this way:

remove CollectionViewSource from your resources and use simple binding

```
<Window.Resources>

</Window.Resources>
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding DeviceList}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Device name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=DeviceName}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Rssi" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Rssi}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="GPS Row" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=GpsSignal}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

set the datacontext for your window to your MainWindowViewModel in codebehind or xaml.
instead of using OnClick, pls use ICommands (RelayCommand or DelegateCommand)

```
<Button Command="{Binding MyCommand4GpsSignalIsTrue}" />
```

Comment: My question would be,I should implement`INotifyPropertyChange` for my `MyDeviceInfo` **and** make the second suggestion you made in regards to `collectionviewSource` or making the second change is a workaround for the first suggestion? cuz I am thinking in this case I am lucky and the `dll` for the 32feet library is not `sealed` and I can make modification on the `MyDeviceInfo` class that I inherited from it. What would be my solution if this wasn't the case? I mean I wouldn't have an access to that class contents to go implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Just want to understand the wholething

Comment: removing CollectionViewSource and using simple binding you can do always :) and yes if you want use binding with your MyDeviceInfo and wanna see changes (and not just initial values!) you have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged. i can just help you with wpf binding stuff. if you wanna use it you have to know some important rules: You can just bind to public properties. Your can just see changes if your object you bind to implement INotifyPropertyChanged. If your binding dont work check the both statements above - if they are right then your DataContext is wrong or your Binding expression. :)

Comment: thanks heaps for the great explanation. I will definitely keep them in mind.